# How to use Interaction.EventTrigger and bubbling custom events in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, routed-events

I am trying to handle a `RoutedEvent` from a `UserControl` I built by hooking it up to a command using `Interaction.Triggers`. The following works--it calls the `AddingNewThingCommand`:

```xaml
<WrapPanel>

    <local:MyCustomUserControl Header="MyHeader1"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddingNewThing">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.AddingNewThingCommand, ElementName=rootViewElement}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </local:MyCustomUserControl >

    <local:MyCustomUserControl Header="MyHeader2"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding List2}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddingNewThing">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.AddingNewThingCommand, ElementName=rootViewElement}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </local:MyCustomUserControl >

</WrapPanel>
```

Now I actually have a lot of these user control instances in this wrap panel, so I would prefer to move the interaction triggers to the parent element -- the WrapPanel. The following does not work:

```xaml
<WrapPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <!-- Also tried local:MyCustomUserControl.AddingNewThing -->
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MyCustomUserControl.AddingNewThing">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.AddingNewThingCommand, ElementName=rootViewElement}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <local:MyCustomUserControl Header="MyHeader1"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding List1}"/>
    <local:MyCustomUserControl Header="MyHeader2"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding List2}"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Does EventTrigger work with bubbling events?

My RoutedEvent:

```c#
    public static readonly RoutedEvent AddingNewThingEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "AddingNewThing", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyCustomUserControl));
    public event RoutedEventHandler AddingNewThing
    {
        add { AddHandler(AddingNewThingEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(AddingNewThingEvent, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, the routed event system permits handlers for any routed event to be attached to any `UIElement` or `ContentElement`. That's how the routed events work.

However, the `System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger` is not a part of the visual tree and therefore cannot participate in this routed event dispatching. The `EventTrigger` subscribes directly to the CLR event with given `EventName` (using Reflection: `Type.GetEvent`).

The event source object will be determined using the following order:

1. If `SourceObject` property of the `EventTrigger` is set, try to get that object. If it's not null, use it.
2. If `SourceName` of the `EventTrigger` is set, get the object using a named objects resolver.
3. Otherwise, use the associated object the `EventTrigger` is directly attached to.

The `EventName` has to be a simple event name. Fully qualified event names (i.e. `Type.EventName`) are not supported. This is in contrast with `System.Windows.EventTrigger`, where you can specify the fully qualified routed event name in the `RoutedEvent` property.

So in short, you cannot simplify your `WrapPanel` in that way.
Maybe you could use an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel` and define a `DataTemplate` containing your `MyCustomUserControl` with the `EventTrigger`s.